# How do I use an rsa securId like device to secure a Joomla website?

Tags: security, joomla, rsa

I've got a joomla website (Community Builder with CBSubs) purchased through joomlapolis.  The client wants to secure authentication with an rsa device.  If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSA SecureID devices are expensive. -- Not the token carried around but the server-side piece. Here's a wikipedia article on alternatives: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token

In all these cases, you'll need to install the server side software and integrate it yourself into Joomla authentication.